# I want to list all the photos to grid view from device react native

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native, wants to show all gallery images into a grid view into react native.
Please help me i got stuck here.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. When asking a question, you will get much better answers if you provide code. Add what you have tried so far. Also please check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please post your code then only we can help.

Comment: <Image source={{uri:'/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/abc.jpg'}} />
 <Image source={{uri:'file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/abc.jpg'}} />
None of one is working 
and i want to display whole images into app like Xender

Comment: This is a  gift for you: https://github.com/saleel/react-native-super-grid

Answer (score 1):

Since your question seems not to be about your specific code, here are some tutorials about the camera roll:

- https://medium.com/react-native-training/mastering-the-camera-roll-in-react-native-13b3b1963a2d
- https://www.codementor.io/blessingoraz/access-camera-roll-with-react-native-9uwupuuy0
- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll.html

I hope it helps.

Comment: R u serious? Camera Roll and grid view :D.

Comment: Well I thought that with "gallery images" he means the camera roll. And the tthe first tutorial explains right how to put them in a grid. Maybe I understood it wrong...?

Comment: i don't know, but i think it's mean he want to show list of image like gallery grid view.

Comment: Well, you might be right. Since this question is 3 days old and he did not react again, I guess we will never find out ;)